# How can I portably send a C struct through a network socket?

Tags: c, portability

Suppose I have a C struct defined as follows :

```
typedef struct servData {
    char max_word[MAX_WORD];
    char min_word[MAX_WORD];
    int word_count ;
} servSendData ;
```

where 'MAX_WORD' could be any value.
Now if I have an instance of this structure :

```
servSendData  myData ;
```

And if I populate this instance and then send it over the network, will there be any portability issues here considering that I want my server as well as the client to be running on either a 64-bit system or a 32-bit system.

I am going to send and receive data as follows :

```
//server side
strcpy(myData.max_word, "some large word") ;
strcpy(myData.min_word, "small") ;
myData.word_count=100 ;
send(sockFd, (char*)&myData, sizeof(myData);

//client side
recv(sockFd, (char*)&myData, sizeof(myData);
printf("large word is %s\n", myData.max_word) ;
printf("small word is %s\n", myData.min_word) ;
printf("total words is %d\n", myData.word_count) ;
```

Comment: relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5660458/3079266

Comment: You should research TLV (type, length, value) encoding and 'serialization' and XDR (external data representation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As other relies have stated there are real problems in copying a C structure between different machines with different compilers/word size/and endian structure.  One common way to resolve this issue is to transform your data into a machine independent format, transfer it across the network and then transform it back into a structure on the receiver.  This is such a common requirement that multiple technologies already exist to do this - the two that spring to my mind initially are [gsoap](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/soap.html) and [rpcgen](http://docs.freebsd.org/44doc/psd/22.rpcgen/paper.pdf) although there are probably many other options.

I've mostly used gsoap and after you get past the initial learning curve you can develop robust solutions that scale well (with multiple threads) and which handles both the networking and data translations for you.

If you don't want to go down this route then the **safest** approach is to write routines that convert your data to/from a standard string format (if you have issues with Unicode you'll need to take that into account as well) and then send that across the network.

Comment: Yes @Jackson you are right regarding the recv() function. In the actual code I am ensuring that the entire data is received before I start reading the individual fields.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, there definitely *will* be portability issues.

Alignment of structure members can be different even among different compilers *on the same platform*, let alone different platforms. And that's all assuming that `sizeof(int)` is the same across all of them (though granted, it *usually* is --- but do you really want to rely on "usually" and hope for the best?).

This holds even if `MAX_WORD` is the same on both computers (I'll assume they are from here on out; if they're not, then you're in trouble here).

What you need to do is send (and receive) each field separately. There is also a problem with `sizeof(int)` and endianness, so I've added a call to `htonl()` to convert from system to network byte order (the inverse function is `ntohl()`). They both return `uint32_t` which has a fixed, known, size.

```
send(sockFd, myData.max_word, sizeof(myData.max_word)); // or just MAX_WORD
send(sockFd, myData.min_word, sizeof(myData.min_word));
uint32_t count = htonl(myData.word_count); // convert to network byte order
send(sockFd, &count, sizeof(count));

// error handling!
if((ret = recv(sockFd, myData.max_word, sizeof(myData.max_word))) != sizeof(myData.max_word))
{
    // handle error or read more data
}
... // and so on
// remember to convert back from network byte order on recv!
// also keep in mind the third field is now `uint32_t`, and not `int` in the stream
```

Comment: Note: your `if` condition is wrong. Even if it were true, it wouldn't be an error. An error would be indicated with `-1`.

Comment: @black: Good point, though I was only trying to get the general idea across. I'll fix it up a bit.

Answer (score 1):

You have to take care about the endians.

May you should use hton() or ntoh() functions, to convert between little and big endian.

Comment: I strongly disagree --- endianness is the *least* of his problems here. It is a problem, but `sizeof(int)` and structure padding (due to different alignment of `int`) are the bigger issues here.

Comment: Ok, yes, I understand, an int on a x86 is smaller than an int on a x64 machnine. Instead of int he should use types like uint32_t or something like this.

Comment: @TimČas How come you “strongly disagree” with an answer that is a true subset of your own?  There are more portability issues than endianness and your answer covers them quite accurately but everything this answer says is correct, too.

Comment: @Lui: Well, *generally* not on x86 vs x64 (but `long` usually is). But it can be, it depends on the compiler. This is relevant: http://www.viva64.com/en/t/0012/ --- one system might be ILP64 (64-bit `int`), another LLP64 (32-bit `int`) and another (think embedded) `I16LP32` (16-bit `int`).

Comment: @5gon12eder: Because he's focusing on the issue which is the *least* problematic of them all, and ignoring all the other, much larger issues.

Comment: @Lui: For a real-world case of 16-bit `int`: `IP16L32`, or an extension `IP16L32LL64` (which adds 64-bit `long long`) is the one typically used for 8-bit (and possibly 16-bit) microcontrollers. Some of those have networking capability (either builtin, or via auxiliary hardware; think Arduino w/ Ethernet shield).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [*structure packing*](http://www.grok2.com/structure_packing.html). With most C compilers, you can enforce a specific structure alignment. It is sometimes used for what you need it - to transfer a `struct` over a network.

Note that this still leaves endianness issues, so this is not a universal solution.

Comment: It is also not standard/portable C (or C+POSIX, since we're talking sockets), plus there remain issues with `sizeof(int)`. Using packing typically also bloats the code with software unaligned reads (at least on non-x86, because the vast majority of other architectures do not support unaligned reads/writes at all; in x86, it just makes such reads slower).

Comment: @TimČas: well, I'm not saying this is the way to go, just that it's possible to avoid some compatibility issues this way. Also, `sizeof(int)` will probably not be a problem for OP, as he says that the client and server in his setup will be either both x86 or both x64.

Comment: Well, technically, he said *some* 64- or 32-bit system, but yes, there are probably none around with 16-bit `int`s. *That said*, he may later decide to add a `long` or similar in a structure, and hit the problem; I was trying to address the issue more generically.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not writing embedded software, sending data between applications without serializing properly is rarely a good idea.

The same goes for using raw sockets, which is not very convenient, and feels a bit like "reinventing the wheel".

Many libraries can help you with both! Of course, you don't have to use them, but reading their documentation, and understanding how they work will help you make better choices. Things you have not yet planned can come out of the box (like, what happens when you want to update your system, and the message format changes?)

For serialization, have a read on those general purpose formats:

- Human readable: JSON, XML, YAML, others...
- Binary: [Protobuf](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/), [TPL](http://troydhanson.github.io/tpl/index.html), [Avro](http://avro.apache.org/), BSON, MessagePack, and many others

For socket abstraction, look up

- Boost ASIO
- ZeroMQ
- nanomsg
- Many others